# Sass @mixin : How to use ternary in width property

Tags: sass

```
@mixin setMarginSides($type, $margin: false)
  @if($type==desktop)
    width: calc(100% - if($margin, $margin, 17vw))
  @if($type==mobile)
    width: calc(100% - if($margin, $margin, 8px))
  margin: 0 auto
```

in css

```
width: calc(100% - if($margin, $margin, 17vw));
```

I assume by reading my code you guys will understand pretty quickly what i'm trying to do. If nott just lemme know.
So can someone please explain me, how can i achieve what i'm trying to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the solution like a big boy

```
width: calc(100% - #{if($margin, $margin, 17vw))}
```

Thanks for your help guys.